# Why is the header tag not working and how can I fix this?

Tags: php

I created a radio input and I want to redirect to the page where the user wants.

```
<form action='./redirect.php' method='POST>
    <input type='radio' name='page' value='page1'>
    <input type='radio' name='page' value='page2'>
    <input type='radio' name='page' value='page3'>
</form>
```

And this is the php code

```
<?php
    $pagename = $_POST['page'];
    #Other questions
    header("location: ".$pagename.".php");
?>
```

How can I redirect to another page?

Comment: Side hint: your code is in this form prone to hacking - an intruder could replace the input values by whatever he wants. I recommend you check the $pagename to be one of x possible/allowed values.

Comment: Your code does not redirect because a form needs to be submitted (button of submit type) to be processed. Without submit, you need to use javascript/jquery to listen to the on-click event on the input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I hope this will help you ...*

```
<?php 
     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
         $pagename = $_POST['page'];
         header("location: ".$pagename.".php");
     }
?>
    
    <!doctype html>
    <header>
    </header>
    <body>
        <form method='POST' id="form-id">
            <input type='radio' name='page' value='page1' class="radio"/>
            <input type='radio' name='page' value='page2' class="radio"/>
            <input type='radio' name='page' value='page3' class="radio"/>
        </form>
    </body>
    <script>
        var form = document.getElementById("form-id");
        var radios = document.getElementsByClassName('radio');
    
        for (i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
            radios[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
                form.submit();
            });
        }
    </script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `button` for POST request. Full Code below

```
<form action='./redirect.php' method='POST>
    <input type='radio' name='page' value='page1'>
    <input type='radio' name='page' value='page2'>
    <input type='radio' name='page' value='page3'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

and your php code is

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       $pagename = $_POST['page'];
       #Other questions
       header("location:$pagename.php");
  }
?>
```